# Why does activating Hyper V cause windows 8.1 enterprise to stop booting?

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v

I have read a number of forum posts suggesting an incompatibility with USB 3.0, but these all referred to a gigabyte mobo, whereas I am on an HP laptop. Suggestions?

EDIT

Issue persists after clean install and latest driver updates (including BIOS).

- make/model - HP pavilion m6 k010dx
- platfrom - win8.1 x64 enterprise

Additional notes; hyper-v is enabled (checked off) under "turn windows features on or off" (both Mangagement Tools and Platform) but disabled in Bios. I have yet to test any of the actual functionality, I will try that next if anyone considers it a good idea.

UPDATE

Attempted sysprep as described here; http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/Cannot-boot-if-HP-ENVY-Bios-Virtualization-enabled-for-Win8/td-p/2006815/page/7

Without generalized switch; no effect. With generalized switch, execution fails with non-specific error. Later reinstalled for unrelated reason; currently hyper-V is not checked of under enable/disable features and inactive in BIOS.

UPDATE 2

Installing an earlier version of the Bluetooth driver allowed me to boot with Hyper-V enabled in the bios, but once I enabled it in Win8.1 I stopped booting again.

Comment: More information is required because the windows feature in question should not be doing what you describe be as detailed as possible

Comment: I think I am having the issue described here; http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Desktop-Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/Cannot-boot-if-HP-ENVY-Bios-Virtualization-enabled-for-Win8/td-p/2006815/page/6
I will confirm as soon as I finish provisioning install media

Comment: @Ramhound, the only thing I haven't tried yet is disabling the BT driver, but I kinda need BT on this system.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth.

Especially Ralink. After long time finally I was able to get Hyper V installed and running. 
Disable bluetooth connection (run **ncpa.cpl** or via control panel). Deinstall all bluetooth devices (**devmgmt.msc**) , including **drivers**. If you have hardware button to turn bluetooth off do it. Maybe try to disable it in BIOS.

Reboot (this is a must, becaue drivers are needed to be out of system). Install Hyper V. Reboot once more. Never turn on/install bluetooth again (it is useless on laptop or pc anyway).

Enjoy Hyper V.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: great that you share your knowledge here! There are two ways to improve your answer: 1. as it is, your answer is very concise. Could you please elaborate or explain what your doing and why. 2. We like the answers to link to authoritative sources. If you have any, please add them. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Branislav nailed the issue!

If you are stuck in the boot screen/loop, boot into safe mode and do the following, if not do this after you enable the HyperV check box in Windows features and before you restart

Uninstall the bluetooth driver and make sure the check box "delete drivers from machine" is enabled in the dialog that prompts when uninstalling bt driver.

I am using HP G6-2314AX and it has RaLink bluetooth builtin :p After uninstalling it, Hyper V works like charm!

Comment: I don't have BT devices and still most of the sometimes hangs. Machine is i7 on ASRock h170m pro4. Sometimes works if I disable fastboot.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is to update your RaLink driver if you are using RaLink... Or it could be another driver issue.

This really works especially if you happen to have an HP 700-074 PC

Don't worry about deleting drivers, etc... or reinstalling windows or anything else that will really frustrate you.

JUST UPDATE THE RALINK DRIVER !!! THIS SOLUTION WORKS !!!

Comment: Yea sorry dude at this point 8.1 is basically a non-issue

Comment: Didn't you see the question the OP asked referenced windows 8.1? Dude?